# Why does my state not appear to be updating in my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to Redux, though I have done a bit of work with React before.

I'm using a [tutorial](https://decembersoft.com/posts/redux-hero-part-1-a-hero-is-born-a-fun-introduction-to-redux-js/) to test using Actions, Action Creators, and Reducers in my application, and so far I think I'm about 90% of the way there.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.levelUp();
    this.props.levelUp();
    this.props.levelUp();
    this.props.levelUp();
    this.props.levelUp();
    console.log("final prop");
    console.log(this.props);
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("state general");
  console.log(state.general);
  return {
    general: state.general,
  };
};
```

Both of the console logs get triggered here, and they increment with each level up operation or decrement with every level down operation.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(generalActions, dispatch);
}
```

This is in my reducer file:

```
export default (state = 1, action) => {
  console.log(state);
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'LEVEL_UP':
      console.log(action.type);
        return state + 1;
      case 'LEVEL_DOWN':
          return state - 1;
    }
    return state;
  };
```

My console logs here seem to be capturing the right increment - the value in the reducer goes up one every time I call this.props.levelUp()

However when I do the final logging of the props in `componentDidMount()`, the value is 1.

Why is this? Am I not persistently saving the data? Is there some other reason why I'm not returning state the way I am envisioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` will be fired **once** the component did mount. Afterwards your actions are fired hence why you should do your `console.log()` statements inside of something like `componentDidUpdate()` or `static getDerivedStateFromProps()`.

More about lifecycles in react: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Greetings

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thank you very much. I'll read more on React life cycles.